# Eloquent loaded with relations

Tags: eloquent

```
class Market extends Model{
    protected $table = 'Markets';

    protected $primaryKey = 'maid';

    protected $guarded = ['maid'];

    protected $casts = ['trade' => 'boolean'];

    protected $with = ['textbook'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function textbook(){
        return $this->hasMany(Textbook::class, 'isbn13', 'isbn13');
    }
}





class MarketController extends Controller{
    public function get($request, $response){
        $market = Market::with('textbook')->paginate();

        return $response->withJson($market);
    }   

}
```

I have an Eloquent Collection with some relations let's say Market and Textbook. I have the relations working just fine. My question is how can I modify my collection to be nested. That is, right now it returns the information about the book and then I can load the relation textbook. 
Currently I have:

```
{
        "maid": 1,
        "meid": 388,
        "coid": 139719,
        "isbn13": "9780718197049",
        "quality": 8,
        "price": 99,
        "trade": 0,
        "notes": "Brand new book at used price!",
        "timecard": "2018-01-08 07:38:38",
        "textbook": []
}
```

But I want something like this:

```
{
    "maid": 1,
    "meid": 388,
    "coid": 139719,
    "isbn13": "9780718197049",
    "quality": 8,
    "price": 99,
    "trade": 0,
    "notes": "Brand new book at used price!",
    "timecard": "2018-01-08 07:38:38",
    "textbook": [
        {
            "isbn13": 2147483647,
            "isbn10": "0718197046",
            "title": "Economics: The User's Guide",
            "subtitle": "A Pelican Introduction",
            "authors": "Ha-joon Chang",
            "publisher": "Penguin UK",
            "published": "2014-05-01",
            "edition": null,
            "volume": null,
            "pages": 304,
            "categories": "Business & Economics",
            "description": "What is economics? What can - and can't - it explain about the world? Why does it matter? Ha-Joon Chang teaches economics at Cambridge University, and writes a column for the Guardian. The Observer called his book 23 Things They Don't Tell You About Capitalism, which was a no.1 bestseller, 'a witty and timely debunking of some of the biggest myths surrounding the global economy.' He won the Wassily Leontief Prize for advancing the frontiers of economic thought, and is a vocal critic of the failures of our current economic system.",
            "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=93rAAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I accomplish the above (nested) result and where I place that code!

Comment: Please post the query code and the relevant relations.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I have included it!

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I assume `textbook` is empty because the market doesn't have any textbooks. In your example the values of `isbn13` don't match.

Comment: It does have books!

Comment: What's the result of `dd(Market::withCount('textbook')->get()->pluck('textbook_count'));`

Comment: The relation works. I just want to know how I accomplish the structure showed in the second block

Comment: If the relation works, `textbook` is empty because the market doesn't have any textbooks.